# How to effectively manage inventory with BigCommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I have am trying to make a tool to manage inventory levels between my warehouse system and my bigcommerce store.  The issue I am running into is the Bigcommerce only sets inventory levels based on the Ids/Variant Ids.  My warehouse software only knows products by sku/subsku.

The first step in the process is getting the ids and variant ids and storing them for current use and later usage.
I do this by calling **"catalog/products"**  and getting all the products for the catalog through a series of calls to build a complete list.  I loop through and then do the same for the variants **"catalog/products/{0}/variants"**

With this list I match my skus and variants to the catalog list returned.  Update the matching skus to big commerce id/variant ids for future and then finally I begin the process of actually updating inventory levels.

I then begin updating the product by calling the endpoint **"catalog/products/{id}"** 
or 
**"catalog/products/{id}/variants/{variantId}"**

This process takes way too long even for a few quantity level updates.  Is there a better way?
I have also noticed that sometimes the big commerce ids will change for some skus.  Which require a complete resync.

Are there better endpoints to use?  Is there a way to update an item based on the sku not the id/variantid?

My solution is in C# but code is not the problem.  The problem is what to call and if there is a better way to call the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One area I see an opportunity to streamline the API calls is here:

> I do this by calling "catalog/products" and getting all the products
>   for the catalog through a series of calls to build a complete list. I
>   loop through and then do the same for the variants
>   "catalog/products/{0}/variants"

You can get products along with their variants by including variants as a subresource using the `?include=` param. For example:

```
catalog/products?include=variants
```

There would still need to be some kind of mapping from variantID to SKU, but when it comes to pushing the updated inventory to BigCommerce, we're also close to releasing updates that will allow you to batch update up to 50 products or variants in a single call. Keep an eye on our Changelog for that announcement: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog

Comment: Any chance you will have an endpoint that will update via sku?  The sku to sync process is my weakest link right now.

Comment: this speed up the process tremendously.  thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped! We don't have short term plans to update via SKU--the variant ID is really the record of truth in our system because it's immutable (if you're seeing IDs change for some SKUs, it makes me wonder if they might be getting deleted and recreated). It's good feedback though--we'll take it back to the team for discussion.

Comment: Is there a way to track inventory per location in BigCommerce?

Comment: @J.J. Today, there's not really a native way to track inventory for multiple locations within the platform. We'd recommend using an app like Brightpearl: https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/brightpearl to manage that externally. For what it's worth though, we're working on building the APIs to support that scenario natively in the future.